# Faster Number Counter Using Only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, velo

The setInterval() method like below takes a lot of time for larger numbers such as 7,000,000 (70 seconds)

```
let startNum = 0;
let endNum = 7000000;    

function countIni() {
       var handle = setInterval( ()=> {
          if (startNum <= endNum) {
             var x = startNum.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                minimumFractionDigits: 0,
                maximumFractionDigits: 0
             });
             $w('#number').text = x.toString();
             startNum++;
          } else {
             clearInterval(handle);
          }
       }, 0);
    }
```

Is there a way the count from 0 to 7,000,000 or higher can be performed within 2 to 3 seconds. Something like this: https://teamtrees.org/

I am using Corvid so I can only use the **$w("#number").text** function to set the value of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to do some calculation for a delta to increment the number. Right now the following is doing 33ms which is about 30 frames per second of animation:

Note that [there is no guarantee for the `delay` passed to `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified). Even a `0` means every next event cycle for `setInterval` (or the next event cycle for `setTimeout`), and is not really "immediately".

```js
let startNum = 0,
  endNum = 7000000,
  nSecond = 2,
  resolutionMS = 33,
  deltaNum = (endNum - startNum) / (1000 / resolutionMS) / nSecond;

function countIni() {
  var handle = setInterval(() => {

    var x = startNum.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 0,
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
    });
    document.querySelector('#number').innerHTML = x.toString();
    
    // if already updated the endNum, stop
    if (startNum >= endNum) clearInterval(handle);
    
    startNum += deltaNum;
    startNum = Math.min(startNum, endNum);
  }, resolutionMS);
}

countIni();
```

```html
<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: I should count number one by one, so in my case deltaNum should be 1.
Is there any other way to speed up the count?